# Sharing same legends for subplots in plotly

Tags: python-3.x, plot, plotly, legend, subplot

I've two plots created in the same figure using `subplots` in plotly.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(20, 5)), columns=list('tABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(20, 5)), columns=list('tABCD'))

fig = go.Figure()
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=df.t,
                y=df['A'],
                name="1",
                line_color='deepskyblue',
                opacity=0.8,
                legendgroup='group1'),
                row=1, col=1
                )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=df.t,
                y=df['B'],
                name="2",
                line_color='dimgray',
                opacity=0.8,
                legendgroup='group2'),
                row=1, col=1
                )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=df.t,
                y=df['C'],
                name="3",
                line_color='blue',
                opacity=0.8,
                legendgroup='group3'),
                row=1, col=1
                )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=df.t,
                y=df['D'],
                name="4",
                line_color='red',
                opacity=0.8,
                legendgroup='group4'),
                row=1, col=1
                )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=df2.t,
                y=df2['A'],
                name="1",
                line_color='deepskyblue',
                opacity=0.8,
                legendgroup='group1'),
                row=1, col=2
                )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=df2.t,
                y=df2['B'],
                name="2",
                line_color='dimgray',
                opacity=0.8,
                legendgroup='group2'),
                row=1, col=2
                )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=df2.t,
                y=df2['C'],
                name="3",
                line_color='blue',
                opacity=0.8,
                legendgroup='group3'),
                row=1, col=2
                )

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=df2.t,
                y=df2['D'],
                name="4",
                line_color='red',
                opacity=0.8,
                legendgroup='group4'),
                row=1, col=2
                )

fig.write_html('ts.html', auto_open=True)
```

Output: 
[image]

I want to share the same legends for both subplots. So, I tried specifying a legend group ([ref](https://community.plot.ly/t/graphs-sharing-same-legend/12476/5)). It works, but duplicate labels appear

Any suggestions on how to remove the duplicates will be helpful

Comment: Using , `showlegend=False` helped!. The problem is resolved.

Comment: Please answer your own question so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Adding `showlegend = False` in the instance where df2 is accessed will remove the duplicate legends

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
                x=df2.t,
                y=df2['A'],
                name="1",
                line_color='deepskyblue',
                opacity=0.8,
                legendgroup='group1',
                showlegend=False),
                row=1, col=2
                )
```

Comment: It's important to note that you should also set the `legendgroup` property to the same value as your other trace. I added `showlegend=False` without `legendgroup` and it didn't work.

Comment: Agree with @lukeic: without `legendgroup`, the duplicate legends are not shown, but clicking on the legend does not hide all of the curves. And naturally, the `legendgroup` should be different for different groups. This is not the case in this answer.